# JS vertical bar chart with time (H:i:s) on Yaxis

Tags: javascript, charts

I have a huge problem to customize a bar chart. I want to 'draw' bars which will represent duration of something (for example duration of failure) in H:i:s time format on the Yaxis. I tried to modify chartjs library but it doesn't work correctly.

Finally I have created mysql query which gets sum of time in H:i:s format.

There is something I tried (I know it is not bar chart, but it doesn't matter at the moment):

http://jsfiddle.net/L4c09v19/

And I tried to do something with:

```
scaleLabel : "<%= value.substring(0,2) + ':' + value.substring(3,5) + ':' + value.substring(6)   %>"
```

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you can do the following: 1) Show a sketch of the chart you want to get done [others might be able to suggest a better library] 2) Show what you have tried with chartjs

Comment: Edit Your question And post the code

Comment: I have updated my question